# Leitura de um ficheiro

Tags: c

Estou a tentar ler o conteúdo de um ficheiro para uma string, para depois usar essa mesma string nalgumas operações.

Neste momento tenho a seguinte função (neste momento apenas lê e imprime o conteúdo):

```
char* ler_ficheiro(char* file_name){
int iSource,n;
char *buff;
char *buffer_retorno;

iSource = open(file_name, O_RDONLY);

if(iSource == -1){
    close(iSource);
    exit(1);
}

while(n = read(iSource, buff,1) > 0){
    printf("%s",buff);
}
return buffer_retorno;
}
```

O meu problema é que quando corro o programa obtenho o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguns destes caracteres fazem parte do conteúdo do ficheiro, mas nem todos.

Tenho então duas questões a fazer:

1.Porque razão isto acontece?

2.Quais as possivies soluções?

**Conteúdo do ficheiro:**
e106265f-bc8a-483c-b25d-f1f5ef1ec7b7 GUA

Comment: Mas porquê estas a usar os sys calls ao inves das funcoes tradicionais de leitura de arquivos??

Comment: O meu professor incentiva os alunos a usar sys calls devido ao tema da cadeira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a função `read` não aloca memória para o buffer. Isso significa que você precisa primeiramente inicializar o ponteiro `buff` com um endereço válido. Ex:

```
char* buff  = malloc(size);
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.